¿Como obtengo un data frame que condense los cálculos con determinadas celdas y después lo pongo en un gráfico de barras apiladas?
Tengo un data frame que contiene la frecuencia de especies para distintos sitios y quiero calcular lo que se denomina huella metabólica para cada grupo trófico y representar los valores apilados en un gráfico de barras? Este es el data frame:

HuellaFito<-apply(tabla[,5:7],2,function(x) sum(x[c(1:19,22:24)]*(0.1*(tabla$Wt)/(tabla$Cp)+0.273*((tabla$Wt)^(0.75))),na.rm=TRUE))
HuellaBact<-apply(tabla[,c(5:7)],2,function(x) sum(x[c(25,26,28)]*(0.1*(tabla$Wt)/(tabla$Cp)+0.273*((tabla$Wt)^(0.75))),na.rm=TRUE))
HuellaOmni<-tabla[tabla$Clasificación=="Om4",c(5:7)]*(0.1*(tabla$Wt)/(tabla$Cp)+0.273*((tabla$Wt)^(0.75)))
HuellaPred<-tabla[tabla$Clasificación=="Pr4",c(5:7)]*(0.1*(tabla$Wt)/(tabla$Cp)+0.273*((tabla$Wt)^(0.75)))
HuellaFung<-apply(tabla[,c(5:7)],2,function(x) sum(x[c(19:20)]*(0.1*(tabla$Wt)/(tabla$Cp)+0.273*((tabla$Wt)^(0.75))),na.rm=TRUE)) 

El cálculo de la huella metabólica se podría resumir en un solo comando (que condense) para generar el data frame y aplicar el gráfico de barras apiladas? También tengo problemas para calcular la huella en caso de tener que usar el valor de una celda por columna como en HuellaPred o HuellaOmni.
Saludos.
Si quieren el dataframe este es mi correo farid1000.fs@gmail.com.
Sá, Farid Leonel.
